# Export displacy graphics as an image file shows an empty file

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, nlp, spacy, displacy

I want to export displacy graphics as an image file. I run the following code block in Jupyter Notebook and generate an svg file name sample.svg.

The code block is

import spacy

```
from spacy import displacy
from pathlib import Path

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')

sentence_nlp = nlp("John go home to your family")
svg = displacy.render(sentence_nlp, style="ent", jupyter = False)

output_path = Path("D:\\sample.svg") 
output_path.open("w", encoding="utf-8").write(svg)
```

The above code gave me an output 393.

When I try to open the svg file by inserting in powerpoint it shows nothing.

I drag and drop the svg file in the Chrome browser.

The result of drag and drop is as follows

[image]

Can any one help me to export the correct svg file format?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Mine worked modifying the `style` parameter to `dep`, so:

```
svg = displacy.render(sentence_nlp, style="dep", jupyter=False)
```

Resulting in the following:
[image: Uploaded .svg in powerpoint]

Hope it helps!